# Log scaling function ticks not showing

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

I am using `ListLinePlot[]` with `ScalingFunctions->{None,"Log"}` to get a log scale on the Y axis, and a frame. But the ticks on the right side of the log axis seem to be on a linear scale. How could I have both sides show log-scaled tick marks?

```
L={1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 27, 36, 49, 67, 87, 112, 143, 170, 203, 239, 
  287, 332, 376, 425, 482, 542, 607, 678, 745, 812, 882, 957, 1040, 
  1126, 1216, 1301, 1400, 1485, 1592, 1705, 1811, 1925, 2040, 2144, 
  2259, 2375, 2508, 2641, 2778, 2915, 3059, 3215, 3374, 3534};

ListLinePlot[L, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Full, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.3, 0.3, 0.3], 14], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed],
 FrameLabel -> {"X axis", "Y axis"},
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]
```

[image]

I am using MMA 12.1 in Windows 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a version 12.0+ glitch. Your code works as expected in version 11.3.

```
llp = ListLinePlot[L, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Full, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.3, 0.3, 0.3], 14], 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], 
    FrameLabel -> {"X axis", "Y axis"}, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]
```

[image]

The issue is caused by the default setting for `FrameTicks`:

```
FrameTicks /. llp[[2]]
    {{Quiet[Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][#1, #2, {6, 6}]] &, 
      Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}, 
    {Automatic, Automatic}}
```

A simple work-around is to post-process to replace `{Identity, Identity}` with `{Log, Exp}`:

```
 llp /. {Identity, Identity} -> {Log, Exp}
```

[image]